# jquery mobile popup message disappear after few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

On master page I have

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {               
     $.mobile.loading('hide');                
});
```

and I'm rendering popup message like this

```
$.mobile.loading('show', { theme: "a", text: "My Text...", textonly: true, textVisible: true });
```

I just need to make this message disappear after 2seconds, right now it stays on top forever.

Comment: Did you try using a timeout? for example `setTimeout(function() { $mobile.loading('hide'); },2000);`

Comment: just tried, doesnt work. Do I need anything else to add except this in master page?

Comment: Well you need to make sure that you set your timeout to fire after the message is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a timeout to execute the code after whateveer interval you want,

for example

```
 //display loading message
$.mobile.loading('show', 
   { theme: "a", text: "My Text..."
      , textonly: true, textVisible: true });

   //execute code after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function () {

    $.mobile.loading('hide');
  },2000);
```

And here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/damajoma/1/)